# How to scroll lock a Jface tableviewer?

Tags: java, jface, tableviewer, scroll-lock

I have a table viewer which is updated very quickly and I want to scroll lock my table viewer as in the eclipse console view.

I tried to plug-in spy the console view in eclipse but I didn't find what I was looking for

Any tips to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the answer, thanks to someone on another forum.
You only need to use the method refresh(object, true, false) to do that

Comment: I have given one snippet to help the people. which is in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33623090/2691625

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work when the `TableViewer` has a `ViewerComparator`